# mount split disk image in raw format

Tags: mount, split

i have a NAS (qnap) where i hosted a LUN a year ago, where i stored some backup data. I made a backup of the lun in raw format (functionality of the nas) and deleted the lun.
yesterday i found out, that i need some files that are stored in the lun. I read in the qnap board, that its possible to mount the drive directly into linux. I have also seen some threads where this is described, but the problem is, that the raw format files are splitted into two files  (1099GB and 190GB) and i really dont know what to do now.

I used fdisk to read out the info of the rawdata, maybe this could help:

First file:

```
Disk Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.000: 1099.5 GB, 1099511627776 bytes
255 Köpfe, 63 Sektoren/Spur, 133674 Zylinder, zusammen 2147483648 Sektoren
Einheiten = Sektoren von 1 × 512 = 512 Bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Festplattenidentifikation: 0xd824e97f

Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.000p1  63  2516576319  1258288128+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Second file:

```
Disk Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.001: 189.0 GB, 188978561024 bytes
255 Köpfe, 63 Sektoren/Spur, 22975 Zylinder, zusammen 369098752 Sektoren
Einheiten = Sektoren von 1 × 512 = 512 Bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Festplattenidentifikation: 0x00000000
```

i hope, that somebody could help me.

best regards!

Comment: If you have the space, you could combine them: `cat Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.00{0,1} > Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage`, or `cat < Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.001 >> Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.000`.

Comment: If the output you posted above is created by an Ubuntu command, you can use `LANG=C ` before it (write `LANG=C mycommand --parameters bla bla`) to set the language to English (fallback) for only this one command. This is useful for posting in English-speaking forums.

Comment: @muru Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)
I was basically going to say the exact same thing, only add how to mount such an image file...  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby I'm not sure OP has the space, but I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enough extra space, you can combine the files. Either add the second part to the first:

```
cat < Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.001 >> Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.000
```

Or create a new image from both, if you 1290 GB of free space:

```
cat Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.00{0,1} > Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage
```

Then it's not very difficult to mount, given the `fdisk` output in your question:

```
sudo mount -o offset=$((512*63)) Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.000 /some/path
```

Where:

- Replace `Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.000` with whatever the name of the final image is (`Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage` if you made a new image, for example)
- 63 is the starting sector of the first partition, as seen in the `fdisk` output
- 512 is the sector size in bytes, also given in the `fdisk` output.
- You might have to specify the filesystem type using `-t`, it's not clear from the `fdisk` output which one it ism exactly.

Comment: I really like the first one!  Didn't think of that!  I wish I could upvote twice! ;-)

Comment: hi thank you very much! yesterday after you commented my post, i tried it and it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

...but if you don't have enough extra space, and you only want to read the partition content, you can install afflib-tools instead and run affuse:

```
affuse Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.000 /some/path
sudo mount -o offset=$((512*63)) /some/path/Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.000.raw /other/path
```

affuse will create a new virtual file in /some/path with extension ".raw". This file is the concatenation of the Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.000 and Backup-LUN-backup-backupStorage.001 (in this order), but without a real copy of those files.

affuse is include in afflib.tools package.